# UITapGestureRecognizer not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing simple menu (UIView). Singleton object encapsulates all drawing and displaying

```
    @interface MenuManager()

@property UIView *menuView;

@end

@implementation MenuManager

static MenuManager *_menuManager;

+ (void)initialize
{
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if(!initialized)
    {
        initialized = YES;
        _menuManager = [[MenuManager alloc] init];
    }
}

+ (MenuManager*)singleton
{
    return _menuManager;
}

- (void)showInView:(UIView*)view animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self prepareMenuViewForRect:view.frame];

    [view addSubview:self.menuView];
    view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}

- (void)prepareMenuViewForRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self.menuView != nil) return;

    self.menuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    NSLog(@"Preparing to draw RECT MENU");
    const CGFloat menuWidth = rect.size.width - 20.0f; // make menu 10pt from sides
    const CGFloat menuItemHeight = 66.0f;
    const CGFloat menuSeparatorHeight = 3.0f;
    const CGFloat menuBottomHeight = 66.0f;

    CGFloat menuHeight = [self getMenuItemCount] * (menuItemHeight + menuSeparatorHeight) + menuSeparatorHeight + menuBottomHeight;
    CGFloat left = (rect.size.width - menuWidth) / 2.0f;
    CGFloat top = 64.0f;



    // Add "Refresh" menu item.-=-----------------------------------------
    UIView *refreshView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(left, top, menuWidth, menuItemHeight)];
    refreshView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x4c4c4c);



    refreshView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(refreshMenuClick)];
    [refreshView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

    [self.menuView addSubview:refreshView];



    top += 100.0f;
    // Adding bottom bar with arrow:
    UIView *dragUpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(left, top, menuWidth, menuItemHeight)];
    dragUpView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xababab);

    UIImageView *dragUpImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_up"]];
    [dragUpImageView setFrame:CGRectMake((menuWidth - 36.0f)/2.0f, (menuItemHeight - 16.0f)/2.0f, 36.0f, 16.0f)];
    [dragUpView addSubview:dragUpImageView];

    [self.menuView addSubview:dragUpView];


}

- (void)refreshMenuClick
{
    NSLog(@"REFRESH MENU CLICK DETECTED!!!");
}
```

refreshMenuClick is not executed. What do I miss?

Inside my View Controller I call up menu like this:

```
- (IBAction)menuBarButtonClick:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [[MenuManager singleton] showInView:self.tabBarController.view animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you actually adding gesture recognizers and composing subviews in `drawRect`?..

Comment: Yes, is that not appropriate place to do this? It's my custom UIView, I figured all need to be placed into drawRect

Comment: Try to add the gecturerecognizer on `refreshImageView`. It may underly between `self` and `refreshImageView`.

Comment: I removed refreshLabel and refreshImageView, so it's just refreshView and still doesn't work

Comment: @katit `drawRect` is the code where you literally draw the content of your custom view. Since your custom view is a composition of other views, it does not look like you need `drawRect` at all. Create subviews in the `init`, and let them do repainting for you. Add gesture recognizers there, too: you need to do it only once.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm going to create singleton `MenuManager` and create/hold to view so I can reuse it when needed (without rebuilding every time)
Doubt it will solve original problem though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've disabled the user interaction for the top level view with this line,

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This will disable user interaction for all this view's subviews as well. You need to set that to YES.

Comment: YES! That was it. I was trying to disable user interaction for underlying views since my menu drawn on top. How do I make sure no interaction can happen under? If I put semi-transparent overlay, will it be enough to "stop" interactions "bleeding through"?

Answer (score 0):

Subviews of the refreshView are catching the recognizer. you can check it by adding recognizer to refreshLabel instead of refreshView.

Edited:

I just tried your code to add to the empty VC and it works fine. Maybe there is something on top of your view

Comment: Tried this, same result

Comment: I just edited my original question. I still have same issue, it's not firing. Removed label and image completely..